# Display ACF order custom field in WooCommerce orders

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields, orders

Need to add a field to the WooCommerce order details page where I can add a tracking number in the order page to be displayed for the customer.

I have added ACF to the order-details.php template as below, but it does not display. When I inspect page element all I can see is `<h2></h2>`. This is my current ACF code:

```
<h2><?php the_field('tracking_number'); ?></h2>
```

Comment: I think this question would better fit into https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: There is an answer to your question: Some feed back will be appreciated on the answer below please. For info, **WooCommerce related questions are off topic on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/…**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following to dis

```
// Display tracking information as a row on order totals everywhere
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_order_item_totals', 'order_item_totals_tracking_row', 1000, 3 );
function order_item_totals_tracking_row( $total_rows, $order, $tax_display ){
    if( $tracking_number  = get_field('tracking_number', $order->get_id()) ) {
        $new_total_rows   = []; // Initializing
        $has_tracking_row = false; // Initializing
        $tracking_row     = array( // tracking information array
            'label' => __("Tracking number", "woocommerce"),
            'value' => $tracking_number
        );


        // Loop through order total rows
        foreach( $total_rows as $key => $values ) {
            $new_total_rows[$key] = $values;
            // Inserting tracking information array
            if( $key === 'shipping' ) {
                $new_total_rows['tracking'] = $tracking_row;
                $has_tracking_row = true;
            } elseif( $key === 'payment_method' && ! $has_tracking_row ) {
                $new_total_rows['tracking'] = $tracking_row;
            }
        }
        return $new_total_rows;
    }

    return $total_rows;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). It should works.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I have added the code to the functions.php however there is no change. It does not display on the front end. What else should I check here?